# What specific use cases would call for a servlet filter outside of Struts2 but within the same web application?

Tags: servlets, struts2, servlet-filters

This question was asked in an answer [Difference between Interceptors and Filters - Is this right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057463/difference-between-interceptors-and-filters-is-this-right), but it remained unanswered.

Can anyone please provide some real time examples on this?
As we can use both Filter and Interceptor for Pre-processing and Post-processing 
of a request.

What would be the use cases(scenarios) where servlet filter is used outside of Struts2 but within the same web application?

Comment: What servlet filter?

Comment: @RomanC, As we can use both filter and interceptor for (pre/post) processing http request. What are the specific use cases in which only servlet filter (javax.servlet.Filter) would be used instead of interceptor and vice versa. If Filter can do such things then what was the need to invent interceptors. I think interceptors were designed to intercept  requests that bypass through Struts framework(<s:form ...>).

Comment: This is not true, interceptors were designed to intercept an action, and change the way before it's executed.

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues combining Apache Shiro (a login framework) with a Struts2 webapp. Because Struts2 was handling the actions of the login (ie using s: tags), a lot of default stuff on Shiro broke such as built-in email validations, remember me and so on.

This also caused Struts2 validation to stop working on Shiro pages (login and createuser) along with JDBC connection problems as I had Struts2 performing actions on sessionfactories built from hibernate.cfg.xml ORM configs, and non ORM connections in Shiro.ini.

In combination with other frameworks, sometimes you don't want Struts2 to handle the actions, as you will have certain issues like I described above. I'm sure there are other examples but this was something I experienced. I lost a lot of built in features provided by Apache Shiro because I had struts handling the actions.